# Unknown file type for wcf rest service json response in iis 7.5

Tags: json, wcf, rest, iis, webserver

I´m facing a problem in my wcf rest service returning a json response. Running the service in Visual Studio 2010 on my local IIS- Webserver worked perfectly.

But now I´m running the same service with the same web.config on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 and when I´m calling the service via

*http://localhost/EchoService/EchoService.svc/echo/123

it doesn´t return the json result but a download dialog with an unknown file type with the json result in it.

First I thought the problem is, that the webserver does not know the json mime type so I added it with:

**Extension:** .json

**MIME- Type:** application/json

**Entry type:** local

But it didn´t solve the problem. Can you please tell me why it is returning the result as a file and doesn´t know the file type?

Here´s my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
         <services>
            <service name="wcf_iis_proto_1.EchoService">
               <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="wcf_iis_proto_1.IEchoService" behaviorConfiguration="webEcho" />
            </service>
         </services>
         <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
               <behavior name="webEcho">
                  <webHttp />
               </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
         </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here is my service contract (left out using and namespace):

```
public interface IEchoService
{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/echo/{message}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   string EchoMessage(string message);
}
```

and service implementation:

```
public class EchoService: IEchoService
{
    public string EchoMessage(string message)
    {
       return "Hey Buddy. You said: " + message + "!";
    }
 }
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be it is expected behavior in your browser. It considers Json as a type to download. To avoid this you should change content type in response to "text/plain". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940502/wcf-rest-webservice-content-type-is-wrong) was discussed how to do this.

Comment: I accessed the service via fiddler and it gets the expected json result just as I wanted. I´m still wondering why it´s working in the browser when hosting on my local IIS but it doesn´t matter, because I want to access the data via application anyway.

Thanks!

Philipp

Comment: By the way. Firefox is showing the result correctly.Must have something to do with the Http Accept Header.