# The remote server returned an error" (400) Bad Request. ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, post

I have a simple WCF POST that posts a simple XML to the service.

This is the service contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "PostTest")]
   Stream PostTest(Stream testInfo);  
}
```

And the configuration, nothing fancy.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="T.Test" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="T.ITest" behaviorConfiguration="web">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Everything works when I test it from a simple client as long as I don't mention the content type.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
```

> req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = null };
xmlDoc.Load("../../PostData.xml");
string sXml = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
Console.Write(sXml + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

req.ContentLength = sXml.Length;
var sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
sw.Write(sXml);
sw.Close();

HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

After some research I understand this is a compatibility issue between soap 1.1 vs soap 1.2. But how do I fix this on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is to do with SOAP version problems because `webHttpBinding` is a REST binding, not a SOAP binding

Setting the `ContentType` header on the request tells the service that the client must respond with the requested content type. What content type do you actually respond with? If it is not `text/xml; charset=utf-8`, then that could explain the error.

According to the documentation, the default response `ContentType` for `webHttpBinding` is `application/xml` or `application/octet-stream` for streamed responses.

And if you do not specify any `contentType` on the `HttpWebRequest`, fiddler tells me that the `ContentType` header is set to `text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*`

The wildcard means that any response type is OK - including the `application/octet-stream` that your server is responding with. Which is why it works if you don't set the content type.

As soon as you set the client `ContentType` header to `text/xml`, it no longer matches what the service is responding with and hence you get an error.

If you cannot set the request ContentType on the client, then you have to do it on the server. This post give a link on how to do that

[WCF REST WebService content type is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940502/wcf-rest-webservice-content-type-is-wrong)

And this gives some more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx

Comment: If you see my service it is Stream which means 'application/octet-stream' so the request and response are both of same content type. If i dont mention any content type in client, it works just fine. But the client is specifying the content type as "text/xml; charset=utf-8", so what is that I need to do on the server to make it work. P.S: I don't have control on the client.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the right direction. This article has complete steps. http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/wcf-rest-service-accepting-raw-xml-webcontenttypemapper/

Answer (score 0):

This has the exact solution for accepting any content type for WCF 
http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/wcf-rest-service-accepting-raw-xml-webcontenttypemapper/